# Shopify OAuth: State parameter useful when the auth server also returns a signed shop id?

Tags: csrf, attack-prevention, oauth, oauth2, nonce

**Background**: I think I understand how the `state` parameter is used in oAuth to prevent [CSFR attacks against the redirect_uri](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.4.1.8).

**Situation**: I am looking at this in the context of implementing a Shopify App and am having problems to see how the recommended `state` check on the client is adding to security in that case.

In Shopify`s oauth flow

- The URL to start the auth flow is tied to a shop (and its logged in admin users), e.g. `https://{shopID}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize`
- The authorization server also sends back a `hmac` signed `shop` parameter (in addition to the `code` and `state` parameters) in its response to the `redirect_uri` – see [Shopify docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth#step-3-confirm-installation)

**Question**:
How is checking the `state` in the auth callback within the Shopify Auth flow improving security?

Given

- That the authorization URL is accessible to logged in shop admins only and
- that we can verify the `shop` parameter (via hmac) on the callback/redirect and tie any actions to the corresponding shop/user within our app.

My understanding is that a CSFR attack could only be carried out by another staff/admin account who can log into the same shop anyway and access the same app (in which case there really is no need to carry out a CSFR in the first place)?

What am I missing here?

Thanks for helping me understand this.